# How can a group of raster objects with same pattern be listed?

Tags: r, r-raster

I have a raster-based function to be ran for many raster objects with different patterns. For 150 cities, the .tif files patterns are this:

```
pattern="_E.tif"
pattern="_ED.tif"
pattern="_SC_t.tif"
pattern="_SH_t.tif"
pattern="_WH_t.tif"
```

for one city, I do this – and works:

```
folder <- "D:/Folder_example"
B <- raster("D:/Folder_example/city1 _E.tif")
B1 <- raster("D:/Folder_example/city1 _ED.tif")
B2 <- raster("D:/Folder_example/city1 _SC_t.tif")
B3 <- raster("D:/Folder_example/city1 _SH_t.tif")
B4 <- raster("D:/Folder_example/city1 _WH_t.tif")
```

the issue arises when I am trying to run for more than one city. So, I have just tried:

```
BB <-list.files(pattern="_E.tif")
BB1<-list.files(pattern="_ED.tif")
BB2<-list.files(pattern="_SC_t.tif")
BB4<-list.files(pattern="_SH_t.tif")  
BB6<-list.files(pattern="_WH_t.tif")

B  <- lapply(BB, raster) #intead of readTIFF that produced error
B1 <- lapply(BB1, raster)
B2 <- lapply(BB2, raster)
B4 <- lapply(BB4, raster)
B6 <- lapply(BB6, raster)
```

And after running the function, I have the following error

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘cellStats’ for signature ‘"list"’
```

Str(B) gave me - for testing in 2 cities

```
List of 2
 $ :Formal class 'RasterLayer' [package "raster"] with 12 slots
```

...which is ok, because I have the 2 cities as a list. My function needs to run for those cities. I also tried

```
B <-list.files(path = "D:/Folder_example", pattern="_E.tif",    full.names=TRUE)
#same for B1-B4
B <-list.raster.files(path = "folder", pattern = "_E.tif")
#same for B1-B4
B <-stack(pattern="_E.tif", full.names=TRUE) 
#same for B1-B4
```

None of last 3 ones options worked.

How can a group of raster objects with same pattern be listed? 
Many thanks, Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to execute a function over all `tif` files in a directory? Not extremely clear from the question, but here is an example of reading all images from a directory into a list object. First create a list of filenames:

```
> n = 20  # test on a small number before processing all images
> for (i in 1:n) { files[i] <- 
        paste0("D:/Folder_example/Raster1_pattern",i,".tif") }
> files
 [1] "D:/Folder_example/Raster1_pattern1.tif" 
 [2] "D:/Folder_example/Raster1_pattern2.tif" 
 [3] "D:/Folder_example/Raster1_pattern3.tif" 
 [4] "D:/Folder_example/Raster1_pattern4.tif" 
 [5] "D:/Folder_example/Raster1_pattern5.tif" 
 ... and so on to
 [n] "D:/Folder_example/Raster1_patternn.tif"
```

To get the images into a list of images, you would do something like:

```
> library(rtiff)
> imagelist <- lapply(files, readTIFF)
```

Instead of `readTIFF` you could also write a function in its place to do something different. This will give you a list that contains the images.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to execute a function over all tif files in a directory – 5 different patterns.
@mysteRious many thanks for your help. It gave me insights on how to approach the issue. However, I believe I asked wrongly – I just edited the question to be more precise. Any help is very much appreciated.